# Iterating over each row and accessing every column in HTTP Sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have explored and tried solution mentioned on Google or StackOverflow but could not solve my problem.
I am trying to iterate over each row of CSV and use every column of a row in "HTTP Sampler"

This is what I have tried till now.
My Test plan structure

[image]

This is my CSV file

[image]

This is my CSV Data Set Config

[image]

I am reading entire CSV and storing values in JMeter properties variable using Bean Shell Sampler.
 
This is the code in Bean Shell Sampler

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

String filename = "load_test_date.csv";
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();

try{
    log.info("starting bean shell");
    File file = new File(filename);
    if(!file.exists()){
        throw new Exception ("ERROR: file " + filename + " not found");
        }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));   
    String line = null;
    log.info("while loop starting");
    headerLine = br.readLine();
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        log.info(line);
        String[] variables = line.split(",");
        props.put("header_1",variables[0]);
        props.put("header_2",variables[1]);
        props.put("header_3",variables[2]);
        props.put("header_4",variables[3]);
        props.put("header_5",variables[4]);
    }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Now I want to iterate over props variable and fetch each column. I tried using While controller and ForEach Controller, but it is not giving me desired output.

**while controller**

[image]

While loop is executing twice (instead of three times for three rows in csv file) and always using last row values
I used ForEach controller too but could not produce desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, forget about Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.
2. Second, if I correctly got your point and you want to iterate all the values, i.e. from 1 to 15, you need different approach, for example read the whole file into memory, split each line by comma and create a JMeter Variable for each "cell" value, example Groovy code would be something like:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   def lines = new File('load_test_date.csv').readLines()
   def counter = 1
   1.upto(lines.size() - 1, { index ->
       def line = lines.get(index)
       line.split(',').each { column ->
           vars.put('value_' + counter, column)
           counter++
       }
   })
   ```

   if you execute the script and look into [Debug Sampler output](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) you will see the following JMeter Variables

   [image]
3. In order to iterate the generated variables you can use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured like:

   [image]
4. And use `${value}` in the HTTP Request sampler to access the next "cell" value on each iteration:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for JSR223 suggestion, I will explore it. 
I guess I have phrased my sentences wrongly. As per my csv file I want to have 3 iteration, one iteration per row and for each iteration, I want to use values in this particular row to call HTTP Sampler.