# JMeter: Get list of column headers and their index

Tags: groovy, jmeter, httprequest

I am looking for a solution to get list of column headers and their indexes.

**Task:** pass column headers from a CSV file and their indexes to a variable for further use in HTTP request. Idea is to create a mapping which would indicate which column to use for the given header, as following example:

| name | position | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | manager | Alphabet |
| Smith | intern | JP Morgan |

So the request would contain:

{"name":0},{"position":1},{"company":2}

I use multiple files where number of columns can be anything from 3 to 50 (or more), so there's no max size. I thought about following approach:

1. Read all headers and split by coma into a list / collection
2. Loop through them and use index of the list items as the index I need:

Headers: `|header_1 | header_2 | ... | heade_n |`

Request: `{"header_1":0},{"header_2":1}...{"header_n":n-1}`

**Question:** How to iterate through all columns while size of the file is unknown?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61735805/8131936) where the OP has a fixed number of columns, and solution uses every value for a separate request, but I have to send only one request with the list of headers and indexes.

**P.S.** I am new to JMeter and Groovy, so didnt have enough time to make a full scale research. So if the answer will explain how to use pass this variable to the request would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "headers" or "columns" in [CSV files,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) there is "first line" and entries delimited by comma.

So if you file looks like:

```
name,position,company
John,manager,Alphabet
Smith,intern,JP Morgan
```

You can generate the desired request body like:

```
def payload = []
def firstLine = new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0)
def entries = firstLine.split(',').size() - 1

0.upto(entries, { index ->
    payload.add([('header_' + (index + 1)): index])
})

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toString())
```

and refer generated value as `${payload}` where required

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Reading a File in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-file-read)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I need to get the value for  given index so the request would be like {"name":0},{"position":1},{"company":2}, i.e. not just "header_{0}"; and with your heads-up and those links, came up with following:

def payload = []
def firstLine = new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0)
def entries = firstLine.split(',')
entries.eachWithIndex{value, index ->
 log.info("'${value}': ${index}")
 payload.add("{'${value}': ${index}}")
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toString())
//log.info('payload : ' + new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toString())

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy to get the names of column headers.

```
File file = new File("<path-to-file-name>.csv")
String header_1, header_2, header_3

file.withReader {reader ->
    def lstColumns = reader.readLine().split(",")
    header_1 = lstColumns[0]
    header_2 = lstColumns[1]
    header_3 = lstColumns[2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to get the value for  given index so the request would be like `{"name":0},{"position":1},{"company":2}`, i.e. not just "header_{0}"; and with your heads-up and those links, came up with following:

```
def payload = []
def firstLine = new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0)
def entries = firstLine.split(',')
entries.eachWithIndex{value, index ->
    log.info("'${value}': ${index}")
    payload.add("{'${value}': ${index}}")
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toString())
//log.info('payload : ' + new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toString())
```